# English equivalent for the Chinese idiom "to pass off fish eyes for pearls"

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests

Are there any (general) English equivalent for the Chinese idiom 鱼目混珠 (to pass off fish eyes for pearls) which basically means to pretend something fake is real? IE:

1. To try and pretend to be someone else
2. To pass off fake products as genuine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sense #1 and #2 we have the idioms/phrasal verbs

> **palm (oneself) off as**
>
> To pretend to be (someone one is not) [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/palm%20oneself%20off%20as)

> **palm something off, palm off something**
>
> Sell or dispose of something by misrepresentation or fraud.
>
> **palm someone off, palm off someone**  *informal* Persuade someone to
> accept something by deception. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/palm_off)

> **pass (someone or something) off as**
>
> To cause people to wrongly believe that someone or something is
> someone or something else
>
> *amateurs passing themselves off as professionals* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pass%20someone%20off%20as)

---

When someone is duped (your sense #2), we in the U.S. sometimes say they were **sold a bill of goods**

> Something intentionally misrepresented: something passed off in a
> deception or fraud—often used in the phrase ***sell a bill of goods***
> m-w

> Originally and chiefly *U.S.* a consignment of merchandise; so in
> colloquial phrase to **sell (someone) a bill of goods**: to persuade
> (someone) to accept something undesirable; to swindle. (OED)

---

A rather dated U.S. idiom, still heard once in a while as jocular advice to *guard against* being duped (sense #2), is

**don't take any wooden nickels**

> Take care and, specifically, try not to get swindled. The phrase is
> thought to have originated in the early 20th century when country
> residents visiting the city were considered easily duped. Primarily
> heard in US. [*Farlex Dictionary of Idioms*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/don%27t+take+any+wooden+nickels#:%7E:text=Don%27t%20let%20yourself%20be,ruses%2C%20including%20obviously%20counterfeit%20coins.)

> Protect yourself (against fraud, loss, and so on). This warning
> against counterfeit coins dates from about 1900 and is distinctly
> American in origin, the nickel being a U.S. or Canadian five-cent
> coin. Why a wooden coin was selected is not known. Presumably making
> coins of wood would always have been more expensive than the intrinsic
> value of metal coins. Several writers suggest it replaced don’t take
> any wooden nutmegs, a now obsolete saying dating from colonial times
> when sharp traders sold wooden nutmegs mixed in with the real spice.
> In print the expression is found in Ring Lardner’s story, The Real
> Dope (1919), “In the mean wile—until we meet again—don’t take no wood
> nickles [sic] and don’t get impatient and be a good girlie.”
> [Christine Ammer; *The Dictionary of Clichés* at
> theFreeDictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/don%27t+take+any+wooden+nickels#:%7E:text=Don%27t%20let%20yourself%20be,ruses%2C%20including%20obviously%20counterfeit%20coins.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps rather old-fashioned now is the idiom **sell someone a pup**.

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sell_someone_a_pup):

> - *sell someone a pup* (UK)
>
> To sell something of little worth, pretending that it is something
> else of greater value.
>
> From an old swindle, where one would be sold a bag purportedly
> containing a piglet, but actually containing a puppy. Compare *pig in a*
> *poke*.

Comment: Not to be confused with "See a man about a dog." :-)